# Add mins in existing custom date format via shell

Tags: bash, shell, date, scripting, sh

I have problem that is using custom date format like `date +%y%j.%H%M%S`,

And what i want is to add 15 mins on the this date on just on current date of system. so that i can use for further calculation into my process.

I have tried with below code -

```
$uprBond=`date +%y%j.%H%M%S`
$ echo $uprBond
16079.031135
$ date -d "$(uprBond) + 5 minutes" +%y%j.%H%M%S
```

> op > bash: uprBond: command not found
>
> 16079.035920

I am failing while passing the above date format , Can anybody please help on this.

Just for note, below is the piece of code is working when i used date function instead of defined date variable i.e. $uprBond **(I don't want to use predefined date because we have some old same formatted date which needs that adding of mins).**

```
date +%y%j.%H%M%S -d "`date` + 5 minutes";
```

> op > 16079.040724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU date, GNU bash 4 and its [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC32):

```
#!/bin/bash

uprBond="$(date +%y%j.%H%M%S)"

year="20${uprBond:0:2}"                 
doy="${uprBond#${uprBond:0:2}}"
doy="${doy%.*}"                         
time="${uprBond#*.}"
time="${time:0:2}:${time:2:2}:${time:4:2}"
in5min=$(date -d "${year}-01-01 +${doy} days -1 day +5 minutes ${time}" "+%y%j.%H%M%S")

echo "now:     $uprBond"
echo "in 5min: $in5min"
```

Output:

```
now:     16079.145026
in 5min: 16079.145526
```